# My navigation bar not working on clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css

On clicking on navigation bar it should direct to different sections of website but it's not directing even using a href and correct id it's not directing.

UPDATE : ALSO SAME THING IS HAPPENING IN FOOTER SECTION NAVIGATION AND IN FOOTER I ADDED ALL THE CLASSES PERFECTLY OF JS THEN WHATS CREATING PROBLEM ?

Working in safari browser but not in others like chrome and android browser

Basically it's responsive but links not working properly.

Any suggestions ?

> Github repo - https://github.com/vivanks/hackoffproject
>
> Webpage link -
>   https://vivanks.github.io/hackoffproject/full-page/index.html

```
<header id="main_menu" class="header">
            <div class="main_menu_bg ">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="nave_menu wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s">
                            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-default" id="navmenu">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                                    <div class="navbar-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                            <font color="black" size="20"><b>{ Hack Off }</b></font></a>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                            <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#domain">About Event</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#pricing">Us!</a></li>


                                            <li><a href="#footer">Support</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                        </div>  
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </header> <!--End of header -->
```

Comment: Works for me. Browser & version?

Comment: Safari it's working not with any others

Comment: Try android @JanKyuPeblik

Comment: I sow some css file called " /assets/css/shimmer.css"   is missing. Do you need it for this menu work ?

Comment: no it's not neccesarry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that in Safari it works but when it does it goes very smoothly to the clicked anchor. This makes me to believe that there is more than plain html here. Here is another example:

```html
<header id="main_menu" class="header">
            <div class="main_menu_bg ">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="nave_menu wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s">
                            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-default" id="navmenu">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                                    <div class="navbar-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                            <font color="black" size="20"><b>{ Hack Off }</b></font></a>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                            <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#domain">About Event</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#pricing">Us!</a></li>


                                            <li><a href="#footer">Support</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                        </div>  
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
      <section id="domain" class="domainsearce">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
      <div class="main_somainsearrce">
       <div class="head_title text-center wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="1s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 1s; animation-name: fadeInDown;">
        <br><br><br>
        <h2>Would you like to know about Hack Off ?</h2>
        <p>IET On Campus VIT presents to you the first hackathon of the institute's academic year. This fall we are set to conduct a hackathon like never before. There will be twenty four hours of brain-storming and coding, which will be accompanied by fun-filled mini-events. Unique problem statements will be given to over 1000 applicants and around 200 oarticipants will be selected for the final hack. It will be a national scale event and an outstanding opportunity for young and brilliant coders</p>
        <br>
        <p>Participants will develop abilities to work with and against participants who are equally motivated to innovate and design real world solutions to various problems and scenarios in todays world. With this event we strive to provide a constructive forum for innovation and coding skills, emphasizing on novelty and efficiency over procedure.</p>
        <br>
        <p>Join us and be updated for an amazing event with participation from students across the country.</p>
        <br><br><br>
       </div>

       

        <!-- End of sercelist -->

      </div>
     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <section id="domain" class="domainsearce">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
      <div class="main_somainsearrce">
       <div class="head_title text-center wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-duration="1s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 1s; animation-name: fadeInDown;">
        <br><br><br>
        <h2>Would you like to know about Hack Off ?</h2>
        <p>IET On Campus VIT presents to you the first hackathon of the institute's academic year. This fall we are set to conduct a hackathon like never before. There will be twenty four hours of brain-storming and coding, which will be accompanied by fun-filled mini-events. Unique problem statements will be given to over 1000 applicants and around 200 oarticipants will be selected for the final hack. It will be a national scale event and an outstanding opportunity for young and brilliant coders</p>
        <br>
        <p>Participants will develop abilities to work with and against participants who are equally motivated to innovate and design real world solutions to various problems and scenarios in todays world. With this event we strive to provide a constructive forum for innovation and coding skills, emphasizing on novelty and efficiency over procedure.</p>
        <br>
        <p>Join us and be updated for an amazing event with participation from students across the country.</p>
        <br><br><br>
       </div>

       

        <!-- End of sercelist -->

      </div>
     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <section id="footer" class="domainsearce">
    </section>
        </header> <!--End of header -->
```

This is basically part of your page where I just wanted to prove that it would work in Chrome with nothing more than just the html. Click on `Support` (the only section I copied for the test) and you will see that it would work on all browsers.

What JS are you using on that site? Seems something to do with that.

Comment: I have included github repo link you can check there a help would be too great for me

Comment: I also took the entire page html from the repo and got the same working result. In https://github.com/vivanks/hackoffproject/blob/master/full-page/index.html if you scroll to the bottom there are plugins.js loaded in the script tag. `<script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>` ... comment that tag and try. Also try commenting out `main.js` etc. Issue seems to be related to the JS loaded which prevents the navigation to the anchors.

Comment: can you suggest about the footer thing ? why footer's navigation is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

You have put wrong class in main.js file. please use follows.

```
  $('.navbar-collapse').find('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 40)
            }, 1000);
            if ($('.navbar-toggle').css('display') != 'none') {
                $(this).parents('.container').find(".navbar-toggle").trigger("click");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you suggest about the footer thing ? why footer's navigation is not working ?

Comment: Did you fixed it? I can't see now the footer links of your website. If you can list the page or code I will try to debug.

Answer (score -1):

check properly the ids for home, domain and pricing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31419054)